# How can I delete these dynamically allocated objects when their container is destructed?

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, dynamic

I have a QList of pointers to QStandardItems which I append to a QStandardItemModel that is used for a QTableView. I want the QStandardItems and the MODDataFile to be deleted when fileListView is destructed. What is the best way to achieve this?

```
foreach (QString fileName, fileList)
{
    MODDataFile *file = new MODDataFile(dir.filePath(fileName)); 
    QList<QStandardItem*> row;

    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem();
    item->setData(QVariant::fromValue(file));
    row.append(item);

    row.append(new QStandardItem(file->mUserInfo["TestID"])); 
    row.append(new QStandardItem(fileName));
    row.append(new QStandardItem(file->mTimeAndLocation["Date"]));

    mFileModel.appendRow(row);
}

ui->fileListView->setModel(&mFileModel);
```

I tried just using QStandardItem objects instead of pointers but QStandardItemModel::appendRow() takes a `QList<QStandardItem*>`. file is a pointer because they are large classes and I want to pass them around to other classes.

Comment: Can you use a `std::unique_ptr` in these?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to pass them around to other classes"? Sounds like you need `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Qt actually cleans up child QObjects automatically(usually), so you don't have to worry about QStandardItem, but for MODDataFile you will have to iterate through the rows and delete them. I don't think unique_ptr would quite work as Qvariant::fromvalue() requires a copy. But shared_ptr would, or since you are already using Qt, you can use QSharedPointer.

Comment: @TonyJ So if I encapsulated the MODDataFile in a QSharedPointer, they will get deleted automatically without needing to iterate through the list, right?

Comment: What is mFileModel? If it is a QStandardItemModel, you don't have to worry, as it takes ownership. Otherwise, it depends on how you built your model. Data should generally belong to models, not gui elements. And @TonyJ, QStandardItem does not inherit from QObject.

Comment: @mapsonyllaer You are right, I confused it with QStandItemModel.

Answer (score -1):

You could replace these lines of code:

> ```
> MODDataFile *file = new MODDataFile(dir.filePath(fileName)); 
> QList<QStandardItem*> row;
>
> QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem();
> item->setData(QVariant::fromValue(file));
> row.append( item );
>
> row.append(new QStandardItem(file->mUserInfo["TestID"])); 
> row.append(new QStandardItem(fileName));
> row.append(new QStandardItem(file->mTimeAndLocation["Date"]));
>
> mFileModel.appendRow(row);
> ```

With:

```
std::shared_ptr<MODDataFile> file = std::make_shared<MODDataFile>();
QList<std::shared_ptr<QStarndardItem>> row;

std::shared_ptr<QStandardItem> item = std::make_shared<QStandardItem>();
item->setData(QVariant::fromValue(file));
row.append( item );

row.append( std::shared_ptr<QStandardItem>( new QStandardItem( file->mUserInfo["TestID"])));
row.append( std::shared_ptr<QStandardItem>( new QStandardItem(filename));
row.append( std::shared_ptr<QStandardItem>( new QStandardItem(file->mTimeAndLocation["Data"])));

mFileModel.appendRow(row);
```

Using `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` will clean up your memory either when you call release on them or they go out of scope. When they go out of scope their destructors will clean up all of the memory and reference counts for you. This also depends on what `mFileModel` is, and how you designed your model.